# Very poor performance in my matplotlib script

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My code here is performing very badly. I barely get more than 10 fps when changing things on the slider. Granted I am not very well-versed with matplotlib, but can someone point out what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Note: I am handling a lot of data, around 3*100000 points in a worst case scenario...
Also not sure if this is needed but I am running on the 'TkAgg' backend.

Here is my code (it is a code to plot and run an SIR epidemiology mathematical model):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import matplotlib.patches as patches

p = 1                                                       #population
i = 0.01*p                                                  #infected
s = p-i                                                     #susceptible
r = 0                                                       #recovered/removed

a = 3.2                                                     #transmission parameter
b = 0.23                                                    #recovery parameter

initialTime = 0
deltaTime = 0.001                                           #smaller the delta, better the approximation to a real derivative
maxTime = 10000                                             #more number of points, better is the curve generated

def sPrime(oldS, oldI, transmissionRate):                   #differential equations being expressed as functions to
    return -1*((transmissionRate*oldS*oldI)/p)              #calculate rate of change between time intervals of the
                                                            #different quantities i.e susceptible, infected and recovered/removed
def iPrime(oldS, oldI, transmissionRate, recoveryRate):             
    return (((transmissionRate*oldS)/p)-recoveryRate)*oldI

def rPrime(oldI, recoveryRate):
    return recoveryRate*oldI

maxTimeInitial = maxTime

def genData(transRate, recovRate, maxT):
    global a, b, maxTimeInitial
    a = transRate
    b = recovRate
    maxTimeInitial = maxT

    sInitial = s
    iInitial = i
    rInitial = r

    time = []
    sVals = []
    iVals = []
    rVals = []

    for t in range(initialTime, maxTimeInitial+1):              #generating the data through a loop
        time.append(t)
        sVals.append(sInitial)
        iVals.append(iInitial)
        rVals.append(rInitial)

        newDeltas = (sPrime(sInitial, iInitial, transmissionRate=a), iPrime(sInitial, iInitial, transmissionRate=a, recoveryRate=b), rPrime(iInitial, recoveryRate=b))
        sInitial += newDeltas[0]*deltaTime
        iInitial += newDeltas[1]*deltaTime
        rInitial += newDeltas[2]*deltaTime

        if sInitial < 0 or iInitial < 0 or rInitial < 0:        #as soon as any of these value become negative, the data generated becomes invalid
            break                                               #according to the SIR model, we assume all values of S, I and R are always positive.

    return (time, sVals, iVals, rVals)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4, top=0.94)

plt.title('SIR epidemiology curves for a disease')

plt.xlim(0, maxTime+1)
plt.ylim(0, p*1.4)

plt.xlabel('Time (t)')
plt.ylabel('Population (p)')

initialData = genData(a, b, maxTimeInitial)

susceptible, = ax.plot(initialData[0], initialData[1], label='Susceptible', color='b')
infected, = ax.plot(initialData[0], initialData[2], label='Infected', color='r')
recovered, = ax.plot(initialData[0], initialData[3], label='Recovered/Removed', color='g')

plt.legend()

transmissionAxes = plt.axes([0.125, 0.25, 0.775, 0.03], facecolor='white')
recoveryAxes = plt.axes([0.125, 0.2, 0.775, 0.03], facecolor='white')
timeAxes = plt.axes([0.125, 0.15, 0.775, 0.03], facecolor='white')

transmissionSlider = Slider(transmissionAxes, 'Transmission parameter', 0, 10, valinit=a, valstep=0.01)
recoverySlider = Slider(recoveryAxes, 'Recovery parameter', 0, 10, valinit=b, valstep=0.01)
timeSlider = Slider(timeAxes, 'Max time', 0, 100000, valinit=maxTime, valstep=1, valfmt="%i")

def updateTransmission(newVal):
    newData = genData(newVal, b, maxTimeInitial)

    susceptible.set_ydata(newData[1])
    infected.set_ydata(newData[2])
    recovered.set_ydata(newData[3])

    r_o.set_text(r'$R_O$={:.2f}'.format(a/b))

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

def updateRecovery(newVal):
    newData = genData(a, newVal, maxTimeInitial)

    susceptible.set_ydata(newData[1])
    infected.set_ydata(newData[2])
    recovered.set_ydata(newData[3])

    r_o.set_text(r'$R_O$={:.2f}'.format(a/b))

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

def updateMaxTime(newVal):
    global susceptible, infected, recovered

    newData = genData(a, b, int(newVal.item()))

    del ax.lines[:3]

    susceptible, = ax.plot(newData[0], newData[1], label='Susceptible', color='b')
    infected, = ax.plot(newData[0], newData[2], label='Infected', color='r')
    recovered, = ax.plot(newData[0], newData[3], label='Recovered/Removed', color='g')

transmissionSlider.on_changed(updateTransmission)
recoverySlider.on_changed(updateRecovery)
timeSlider.on_changed(updateMaxTime)

resetAxes = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.05])
resetButton = Button(resetAxes, 'Reset', color='white')

r_o = plt.text(0.1, 1.5, r'$R_O$={:.2f}'.format(a/b), fontsize=12)

def reset(event):
    transmissionSlider.reset()
    recoverySlider.reset()
    timeSlider.reset()

resetButton.on_clicked(reset)

plt.show()
```

Comment: @JohanC funny you say that but the performance was worse when I did use numpy arrays, maybe I did it wrong, I initialised empty numpy arrays and used the numpy.add() method to add each value. I saw a dip in 2 fps (not much but it wasn't any better either)

Comment: No, no, you need to create the arrays directly having their final size. Otherwise they need to be recreated over and over again. Somehing like `sVals = np.zeros(maxTime+1)` and then use `sVals[i] = ....`. Time should be `np.arange(maxTime+1)`

Comment: Ok, I will try that and let you know, thanks!

Comment: @JohanC I have definitely gained some more frames at low number of points, above 35000 it starts slowing down and near 80000 it is again painfully too slow. Do you have any more advice? Thanks for the above advice by the way!

Comment: An additional idea is to not store every time step, but use `sVals[t / 10] = sInitial` (and only create the array at 1/10th of its size). So, you still use all timesteps for the calculation, but only show 1 in 10 (or 1 in 50 or so)

Comment: @JohanC I don't understand what you are trying to say. If I don't store every time step, how am I to generate all the values? I would have curves that are reduced in length. The reason I added a slider to change the value of plotted point is because when the other sliders are changed, at times, the point of intersection of the curve goes further than the default view will show. So to view this, we extend the curves and view them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proper ODE solver like `scipy.integrate.odeint` for speed. Then you can use larger time steps for the output. With an implicit solver like `odeint` or `solve_ivp` with `method="Radau"` the coordinate planes that are boundaries in the exact solution will also be boundaries in the numerical solution, so that the values never become negative.

Reduce the plotted data set to match the actual resolution of the plot image. 
The difference from 300 points to 1000 points may still be visible, there will be no visible difference from 1000 points to 5000 points, probably even not an actual difference.

matplotlib draws its images via a scene tree as objects, using slow python iteration. This makes it very slow if there are more than a couple 10000 objects to draw, so it is best to limit the number of details to this number.

### Code for the ODE solver

to solve the ODE I used solve_ivp, but it makes no difference if odeint is used,

```
def SIR_prime(t,SIR,trans, recov): # solver expects t argument, even if not used
    S,I,R = SIR
    dS = (-trans*I/p) * S 
    dI = (trans*S/p-recov) * I
    dR = recov*I
    return [dS, dI, dR]

def genData(transRate, recovRate, maxT):
    SIR = solve_ivp(SIR_prime, [0,maxT], [s,i,r], args=(transRate, recovRate), method="Radau", dense_output=True)
    time = np.linspace(0,SIR.t[-1],1001)
    sVals, iVals, rVals = SIR.sol(time)
    return (time, sVals, iVals, rVals)
```

### Streamlined code for the plot update procdures

One can remove much of the duplicated code. I also added a line so that the time axis changes with the maxTime variable, so that one really can zoom in

```
def updateTransmission(newVal):
    global trans_rate
    trans_rate = newVal
    updatePlot()

def updateRecovery(newVal):
    global recov_rate
    recov_rate = newVal
    updatePlot()

def updateMaxTime(newVal):
    global maxTime
    maxTime = newVal
    updatePlot()

def updatePlot():
    newData = genData(trans_rate, recov_rate, maxTime)

    susceptible.set_data(newData[0],newData[1])
    infected.set_data(newData[0],newData[2])
    recovered.set_data(newData[0],newData[3])

    ax.set_xlim(0, maxTime+1)

    r_o.set_text(r'$R_O$={:.2f}'.format(trans_rate/recov_rate))

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

The code in-between and around remains the same.