# Updating parameter value with slider (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider

I have a system of differential equations. The solutions depend on a parameter *beta*. I want to create a slider so I can change this parameter and display the changes of the solution curves directly in my plot. I almost got it I think, but I miss one piece.

My code

```
N = 1

#Initial conditions
I0 = 0.01
S0= N - I0

#System of diff. equations
def system(x, t, beta, gamma ):
    I, S = x

    dIdt = (beta/gamma*S-1)*I*gamma
    dSdt = -(beta/gamma*S-1)*I*gamma

    return dIdt, dSdt

#Parameters initial value
beta = 0.03
gamma = 0.017

#Initial cond. vector
y0 = I0, S0

#time grid
t = np.linspace(0, 1300, 1300)

# Solution 
sol = odeint(system, y0, t, args=(beta, gamma))


################ Animations part ##################

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.25)

#solution curves for I and S
infected, = plt.plot(t, sol[:,0])
recovered, = plt.plot(t, sol[:,1])

axbeta = plt.axes([0.125, 0.1, 0.5, 0.05])

sliderbeta = Slider(axbeta, 'beta', 0, 1, valinit=beta)

def update_beta(val):
    beta_value = sliderbeta.val
    ??????????????????????????????????????
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

sliderbeta.on_changed(update_beta)

plt.show()
```

I don't know how to acces my initial beta value and how to replace it by *beta_value*. I guess there is some line missing where I put the question marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take any ODE integration out of the global scope and migrate it to the update function. Following [Automatically Rescale ylim and xlim in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984085/3088138), one needs to add commands to compute the new limits and apply them.

```py
# line objects for the solution curves for I and S
infected, = ax.plot([0], [0])
recovered, = ax.plot([0], [0])

def update_beta(beta):
    # if triggered as call-back it passes the current slider value
    # Solution 
    sol = odeint(system, y0, t, args=(beta, gamma))
    # update the data for I and S
    infected.set_data(t, sol[:,0])
    recovered.set_data(t, sol[:,1])
    # recompute the ax.dataLim
    ax.relim()
    # update ax.viewLim using the new dataLim
    ax.autoscale_view()
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

And finally, to get an initial plot on startup, call this update function from the global scope once

```
update_beta(beta)
```

Comment: I did as you mentioned. It is not working. I do not need the on_changed method for my slider?

Comment: Yes, one needs to add relim+autoscale to get it to display properly. And everything that I did not mention remains as it was.

Comment: It works now! Thank you! I got one more question: What if I want to add a button, so that on click it animates the transition of beta, say from 0 to 1, automatically? In addition to being able to set it manually like it is now. I'll be happy with an approach.

Comment: This can very quickly get confusing visually if the y axis keeps rescaling. In principle you could make a loop inside the update function and use a pause or sleep function to control the speed. The button would then change if the transition loop has length 1 or 10. But I never tried something like this with matplotlib, so there might be better ways. Also look at matplotlib.animation.